# Code error for creating a table on phpadmin mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    id int(s) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fullname varchar(30) not null,
    phonenumber varchar(10) not null,
    password varchar(20) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

To create a table on phpadmin mysqel